# How to use properly JS includes

Tags: javascript

I have the following script, I have an array and I need to filter my a specific keywords, in this case `GitHub`, the code result false, when instead I need to tweak it to return true.

What am I doing wrong? How to fix it?

```js
const array1 = ["[GitHub](https://github.com/xxx", 2, 3];

console.log(array1.includes('GitHub'));
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not possible with `includes`. You will have to use `.some`

Comment: thanks, what should I use instead? any examples?

Comment: [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) performs an exact match, not an expression match on each element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented `.includes` is not the intended feature. It does exact search and you are looking for a partial search.

#### array.some + String.includes

As correctly pointed out by [@Nick Parsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5648954/nick-parsons), since numbers do not have `.includes`, we will have to convert it to string.

> just a heads up, with the first snippet, if a number appears before a valid match it will throw an error.

```js
const array1 = [5, "[GitHub](https://github.com/xxx", 2, 3];

console.log(array1.some((str) => str.toString().includes('GitHub')));
```

---

#### String.includes

If you have primitive values in array, you can directly use `string.includes`

As commented by [@Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8390411/max)

> "partial search" is rather misleading term. Search by predicate is what it really is

```js
const array1 = ["[GitHub](https://github.com/xxx", 2, 3];

console.log(array1.join().includes('GitHub'));
```

Note, `sytring.includes` is a case sensitive function and will fail for mismatching case.

If you wish to have case insensitive search, either transform both string values to same case or use regex

```js
const array1 = ["[GitHub](https://github.com/xxx", 2, 3];

function test(str) {
  const regex = new RegExp(str, 'i')
  console.log(regex.test(array1.join()));
}

test('GitHub')
test('git')
test('hub')
```

Comment: "partial search" is rather misleading term. Search by predicate is what it really is. Also, second solution will give false positives on `['Git', 'hub']`

Comment: just a heads up, with the first snippet, if a number appears before a valid match it will throw an error. The other snippets don't have this issue though 

Comment: @NickParsons Thanks for pointing out. Have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

> The includes() method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

While `"GitHub"` is a substring of one of the values, it is not an exact match for that value. You cannot use `includes` for this.

---

The [`find` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) allows you to pass a *function* which could do a substring match (using the `includes` method of a String.

```js
const array1 = ["[GitHub](https://github.com/xxx", 2, 3];
const results = array1.find(element => element.includes('GitHub'));
const match = !!results; // Convert to boolean

console.log(results);
console.log(match);
```

Comment: `.find` with `!!` is the same as `.some`